# Using the -command PowerShell feature does not executing in CMD

Tags: powershell, command

I am trying to create a PowerShell command that reads a registy variable and then executes a command. It does this from the command line using CMD and it runs under SYSTEM.

I have the following code:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Minimized -Command 
"$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue' |`
 New-Variable -name UserNameForSapFolderRemoval -Value (get-itemproperty 'HKCU:\Volatile Environment' |`
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName) |`
 Remove-Item $("C:\Users\"+$UserNameForSapFolderRemoval +"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Sapgui 7.30") -Force -Recurse |`
 Remove-Variable -Name UserNameForSapFolderRemoval"
```

But it returns with:

```
The string is missing the terminator
```

I added the " character but without succes.

Any idea how I can get this powershell command to run succesful?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing username from registry is way too complicated, as there already is `$env:username`. Try something like this,

```
powershell -command { rm -force -recurse "c:\users\$env:username\appdata\whatever" }
```

Comment: I use that because the script runs under SYSTEM. I tried the { and } character but without success.

Comment: @user2955447 It would make sense to include such a bit of info in the question.